# Server 2003 remote desktop connections registry manipulation

Tags: windows-server-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Increase Maximum Number of Concurrent Remote Connections in Windows Server 2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/23545/how-do-i-increase-maximum-number-of-concurrent-remote-connections-in-windows-serv)

I was told that their might be a way in the registry to allow more than 2 remote desktop connections. Is this possible and if so how? Even if all you have is a registry key to manipulate that would be helpful.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/23545/how-do-i-increase-maximum-number-of-concurrent-remote-connections-in-windows-serv

Answer (score 4):

Turn on terminal services and properly license your server for the number of remote connections you want.  Anything else is likely violating the terms of your license agreement with Microsoft.

Comment: It isn't "likely violating"-- it *is* violating the terms of the license agreement.

Answer (score 2):

You can get 3 by having the third grab console...  `mstsc /admin /v:address`

I realize that's not specifically what you're after, but figured I'd share. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal Services Configuration\Connections

Right-click on RDP-Tcp, select Properties

Select the "Network Adapter" tab

Change the "Maximum connections:" setting.

---

Keep in mind that you will only be able to allow as many connections as you are licensed for (see Kevin Kuphal's answer).