# Unlimited desktop connections in Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, licensing

I recently installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (64 bit) on a nice machine that's more than capable of handling 30 or so remote desktop connections at once, and this is precisely what I want to do.

Unfortunately, I can only make 2 at a time--because that's what the limit is defined as...

I haven't seen any conventional ways of redefining this limit...

How do I redefine this limit?  **Any** answers appreciated, answers that do not include "setting up a license server" are especially appreciated(!!!)

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I Increase Maximum Number of Concurrent Remote Connections in Windows Server 2003](http://serverfault.com/questions/23545/how-do-i-increase-maximum-number-of-concurrent-remote-connections-in-windows-serv)

Comment: Just a heads up, this question is really a bit of spam as the owner was spruiking their own (illegal) product as an answer. But the question itself is OK so I think we'll leave it.

Answer (score 10):

You haven't seen any "conventional ways of redefining this limit"? really? how about buying Terminal Services CALs? I don't know what's more conventional than paying for the functionality you want.

Basically that's it; just buy the licences, install, ?, Profit - the end.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you're asking for the [same thing as this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/23545/how-do-i-increase-maximum-number-of-concurrent-remote-connections-in-windows-serv/23550#23550).

The product's license agreement explains how to increase then number of remote connections allowed. You setup a license server, install the appropriate CALs, and you'll be allowed an increased number of concurrent connections.

If you don't like those terms I'd recommend using another operating system that offers you license terms that you like better.

Nobody here is going to tell you how to violate the product's license agreement. We don't do that here, being professional systems administrators.

Comment: I did not install the system, I have not read the license agreement.  If there isn't any way to do this for free, I need to be able to do it for not for free.  Where/How can I buy "Terminal Services CALs"?  What is CAL short for?  Is this an additional cost to the license that was already purchased (with the dvd) or do I already have the license and not know it?

Nothing additional has been purchased, if "Terminal Services CALs" do not come with the dvd, I need to be able to get them.

Again, help is seriously appreciated.

Comment: "Client Access Licences" - call who you buy software from, explain the requirement, ask for quote, pay them, it might make sense for them to come and install it for you too from what you've said.

Comment: It does not make sense for them to come and install it--that costs more money...  So I really can't buy this tonight on the internet from microsoft?  Is there not some software I can install right away that could sit and wait for me to have a license key so I can enter it at any time (how ever long it takes for the higher ups to realize they need to buy these licenses) ?

Comment: CAL are Client Access Licenses and they don't come as standard. 

Terminal Server can be run in either Application Server or Remote Administration mode. You are in the latter mode and that only allows two connections and is designed for that purpose (ie for administrators to remotely manage the server and not to allow users to run applications on the server). You don't need any extra TS CALS for that (but you are limited to two connections). You need to switch to Application Mode and for that you need to buy TS CALs for each user that will be using remote desktop to the server.

Comment: Joseph, what worries me and made me suggest you get someone in to install it is that if you didn't know TS CALs and the associated licence manager service existed before tonight can you be confident you'll be able to install it and get it working in your timescales?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Evan and Chopper have stated, you'll need to install the Remote Desktop Services role on the server. (Remote Desktop Services is the new name for Terminal Services).